# How to validate multiple functions before submission?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, eventhandler, onsubmit

So I am trying to validate a form and when I run my code, the validation works and displays the function values, but disappears right after. What am I doing wrong? How can I get it to validate first before submission?

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" id="form" action="#" onsubmit="validateForm()" method="POST">

   <div class="form-group">
      <label id="first" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
      <input id="firstName" name="fname" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="John"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label id="emails" for="email">Email: </label>
      <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="email@domain.com"/>
      </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label id="address1" for="street">Street Address:</label>
      <input id="street" name="street" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="123 Lane Street"/>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit Button">
 </form>
```

JavaScript File:

```
function validateForm() {
   var nameValid = validateName();
   var addressValid = validateAddress1()
   var emailValid = validateEmail();

function validateName() {
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;;
    if (name == null || name == "") {
        document.getElementById('first').style.color = "Red";
        document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = "First Name *Required";
        document.getElementById('firstName').style.f = "Red";
        return false;
    }
}

function validateAddress1() {
    var address = document.forms["myForm"]["street"].value;
    if (address == null || address == "") {
        document.getElementById('address1').style.color = "Red";
        document.getElementById('address1').innerHTML = "Street Address *Required";
        document.getElementById('street').style.f = "Red";
        return false;
    }
}

function validateEmail() {
    var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    if (email == null || email == "") {
        document.getElementById('emails').style.color = "Red";
        document.getElementById('emails').innerHTML = "Email *Required";
        document.getElementById('email').style.f = "Red";
        return false;
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Get the `event` object in your `validateForm` function and run a `event.preventDefault()` before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the default behavior when submitting the form. Add `event` as parameter to the function and then `event.preventDefault();`

Then modify the functions so that they return `true` if the input data is valid and `false` if it is not.

Then verify if at least one of the methods returns `false`, if so, return from there.

Please look at this example

```js
function validateForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var nameValid = validateName();
    var addressValid = validateAddress1()
    var emailValid = validateEmail();

    if (!nameValid || !addressValid || !emailValid) {

        return;
    }

    // programatically submit the form > event.target.submit();
    event.target.submit();
}

function validateName() {
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;;
    if (name == null || name == "") {
        document.getElementById('first').style.color = "Red";
        document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = "First Name *Required";
        document.getElementById('firstName').style.f = "Red";
        return false;
    }

    document.getElementById('first').style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = 'First Name';

    return true;
}

function validateAddress1() {
    var address = document.forms["myForm"]["street"].value;
    if (address == null || address == "") {
        document.getElementById('address1').style.color = "Red";
        document.getElementById('address1').innerHTML = "Street Address *Required";
        document.getElementById('street').style.f = "Red";
        return false;
    }

    document.getElementById('address1').style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById('address1').innerHTML = 'Street Address:';

    return true;
}

function validateEmail() {
    var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    if (email == null || email == "") {
        document.getElementById('emails').style.color = "Red";
        document.getElementById('emails').innerHTML = "Email *Required";
        document.getElementById('email').style.f = "Red";
        return false;
    }

    document.getElementById('emails').style.color = 'black';
    document.getElementById('emails').innerHTML = 'Email:';

    return true;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="form" action="#" onsubmit="validateForm(event)" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label id="first" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input id="firstName" name="fname" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="John" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label id="emails" for="email">Email: </label>
        <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="email@domain.com" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label id="address1" for="street">Street Address:</label>
        <input id="street" name="street" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="123 Lane Street" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Button">
</form>
```

To eliminate the experience of the text in red to be approved a validation, before returning true I guarantee the text of the label this in its initial format

Finally this way of doing the validation can be improved I will try to pass an example